# Remove image corner or make it transparent

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to remove image corner or make it transparent, so the background behind that corner should be visible. Is there any way to do this with Jquery or CSS?

Comment: show your code and what did you tried

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and **include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself

Comment: What kind of image? Use a PNG or GIF as they have built in support for transparency.

Comment: I don't know why people are asking him to show his code, all there would be to show would be a single image tag. This is more of a "how does this work" question, it seems pretty basic to be honest.

Comment: If you're fine with rounded corners you can use the `border-radius` CSS property `img {  border-radius: 30px; }`

Comment: In my opinion this is a request for a type of feature already available. It is a feasible question and since there is no code a broad answer showing the feature to use from an API seems appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this using the [CSS 2.1 clip property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/CR-CSS21-20040225/visufx.html#clipping) or using an SVG and the clip-path property. There is a tutorial on how to do this here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `border-radius`:

```
$("#IDofImage").css("border-radius", "10px");
```

Of course if you just want the CSS set all the time from page-load, use pure CSS:

```
#IDofImage {
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: No need JS to do that ...

Comment: @Kyra -- True, if OP just wants it on page-load then just set the CSS, I was thinking inside of an event. I'll edit.